Win10 Pro 22H2 won't access NAS on my LAN, shown only as Media Device in Explorer
For some reason, my NAS drive is shown only as Media Device instead of "normal" device on LAN.
When I try to open it via shortcut on my desktop I made before when it worked, it says "Windows cannot access \NAS-IP2" (NAS-IP2 is the name of my NAS drive on my LAN).
It worked for many years without any problem, but some time ago I was trying to install some PHP/Apache apps on my PC that needed some special settings regarding SMB (unfortunately I do not remember what they were) and I prolly mangled some settings via CMD regarding SMB1...I guess something like "use SMB2 instead of SMB1" or something like that, or even to use some other server instead of SMB, I dreally do not remember after all this time that have passed since (but not sure exactly).

I checked that I have enabled SMB1: did not help, NAS drive still shown only as Media Device
I checked with Angry IP Scanner
that my NAS drive is "live" and present with no problems
NAS drive is accessible from other PCs on my LAN, even Android phones with no
problem
I've already disabled IPv6 in network adapter settings (as I was told it is one of the possible problems): did not help, NAS drive still shown only as Media Device
I have enabled "Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP" in network adapter settings: did not help, NAS drive still shown only as Media Device
I have enabled "Turn on file and printer sharing" in Advanced Sharing Options: did not help, NAS drive still shown only as Media Device - BUT I NOTICED IT IS IMMEDIATELLY REVERTED BACK TO OFF, WHY - may this be the problem???
I also noticed that windows service called Workstation that is needed for this cannot start as it depends on some other services that are not running but I do not know what those other needed services are :-(((


Hello, do you think you can provide us some logs from the NAS ? in the event viewer for example.

@Maslie Hi there: can you tell me where to find those and how to do it? Sorry, I am no pro, so please bear with me. :-)

If your NAS is on a windows OS, you can go to the event viewer and check system event viewer, to access it, silmply right click on the windows logo and click on event viewer, if it is a linux then you want to check the SYSLOG file in the repertory /var/log/

@Maslie Unfortunately, my NAS drive is a separate machine - not a PC: a box containing two HDD connected to my LAN. :-(

Yo umust have a software to configure and maintain your NAS ?

Yes, I do...so?

What is the name of that software ?

Actually,. it is a web-based configuration (I type its LAN IP address and log in locally via my web browser). The NAS is ZyXEL NSA320S, if it helps.

What Maslie trying to patiently communicate is that you need to go into whatever the admin/control/application interface of your NAS is, and find and review the log files available there. Also, not knowing what changes you may or may not have made to your main computer is a serious issue, as we will not know what your computer is NOT supporting right now. Do you have a 2nd computer that you have not modified that DOES work, or that has its own issues seeing the NAS? Have you tried running something simple like a "live" Linux distro to get a different view of the NAS?

@music2myear I did get what he meant, I just did not know how to do it + if you kindly read my question you would see that I have another PC that works with no problems at all with the NAS, even my android smart phone does work with the NAS without any issue at all. I noticed that for some reason I am unable starting Workstation windows service - may that be the cause?

What I'm also trying to get is the name of the APP so I can search, and try to figure out a way to get those sweet log, now to tell you that if you can't open Workstation windows services is the cause or not will be hard if we have no error message

I see. I can look at the NAS logs now - I found them in the NAS web menu, but there is no error log when I try to open it as the Windows does not even know about it (NAS), thus there are no logs regarding the machine I have problem opening the NAS as device instead of Media Server as there are folders besides Movies/Photos/Music I need to access. I ma starting to think that the main issue that Workstation service that cannot start as it says it depends on some other services that are not running but I do not see what those other services are so I do not know which one to enable/start.

WorkStation service not running IS a major problem. And not just for accessing the NAS. Run the Windows network diagnostics/troubleshooter. With a little bit of luck this will fix the problem. (You may have to re-enable SMB1 support afterwards as your NAS may need that and the network troubleshooter will probably disable it as it has been depreciated for years.) Another thing that might help is the command-line command "SFC /scannow" (you'll have to start that from a Command Prompt or Powershell windows that was started with "run as Administrator").

@Tonny My SMB1 is enabled and running, problem is how to enable/run that Workstation service as it says it needs some other windows services to be running as well but I do not know which ones. Troubleshooter said it was unable to find and fix any problem.

@Tonny SMB1 should never  be enabled - it's fully exploitable and has been actively exploited for almost a decade (having it enabled also makes the entire LAN insecure).

@theoneiam Completely disable SMB1 via optionalfeatures, then reboot, as every device and OS supports SMB2+. If you've been accessing the NAS without credentials, that could be the problem since SMB2+ requires credentials. If you try adding the share in Explorer via it's IP, does it add successfully? To ensure OS doesn't have any system file issues, also execute from an Admin terminal: Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup → Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth → Reboot → Sfc /ScanNow → Reboot

@JW0914 You don't have to tell me how insecure SMB1 is. But a lot of older NAS boxes need it. Including a whole bunch of Zyxel devices. Such devices should be replaced, but many home users don't known/don't care. I have no idea if this particular Zyxel box needs it, but I can' t be bothered to try to look that up (I really don' t like Zyxel).
Good advice on the Dism command. I was not near any PC and had very spotty cell-phone reception. I couldn't easily look up the exact syntax earlier or I would have added that myself.

Solved it myself already...thank you guys anyway!

The solution for me was to re-define dependencies for the Workstation service that was unable to start.
Run CMD as Administrator and type (notice the space after the symbol "=" - it is intentional, it needs to be there exactly as written below!):
sc config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi

Hit ENTER, close CMD window and then restart your PC.
In my case this completely solved the whole issue without doing anything else besides the above mentioned command.
Now I can access my NAS drive again as a computer, not just as Media Device.
